# Play Scala - Strategy to send large data with HTTP Request

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I would like to get some advice on how to send large datasets using the `Play WS`. I'm making some computations from a binary file and resulting to `Map[String, List[Double]]`and I want to send this `Map` using a `HTTP POST`. The `List[Double]` is a list of points present in the binary file. The thing is that in a first time, I converted the `Map[String, List[Double]]` to JSON and the resulting size is 8.1MB. My questions are :

1. Is it large to send 8.1MB through the network?
2. Using JSON is a good practice for such use case?
3. Is it an better way to make the request with such data?

I'm looking for some advice about this and also, it's the first time that I met a such situation.

Thank you

Comment: give some more information, what is your data, are you just transfering binary files or some other data

Comment: The data comes from a binary file and I applied to it some operations to get a `Map` of points. What I want to transfer, is the `Map[String, List[Double]]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. 8.1 MB is large for a normal post request, yes.
2. The best thing would be to send it as a stream of bytes (Serialization), but if that is not possible, then JSON is second best (less verbose than XML)
3. I would say use standard form file submission utility to break down your Map[String, List[Double]] JSON file into multiple parts and update progress as it is sent. When the upload is complete, notify the server to process the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [sending large amounts of data from a stream](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream#sending-large-amounts-of-data). In your particular case, I would focus on the chunked responses.